# Creating a PHP registration class + templating system?

Tags: php, sql, class

As of right now I've created a template class, and I've created a registration class. But I'm having trouble getting the two to work properly together so that I can display my variables in my template files.

Here are the basics of my template class:

```
class siteTemplate {
    function getTemplate($file, $varesc=false) {
        if (file_exists("templates/" . $file)) {
            $data = file_get_contents("templates/" . $file);
            $data = str_replace("\"","\\\"", $data);
            $data = str_replace("\'","\\\'", $data);
            $data = str_replace("\\n","\\\n", $data);
            if($varesc)
                $data = str_replace("\$","&#36;", $data);
                return $data;
            } else {
                die("Error.<br />Could not find <strong>" . $file . "</strong>.");
            }
    }
    function createGlobal() {
        global $siteName, $siteUrl;
        global $content;
        eval("\$main = \"".$this->getTemplate("main.html")."\";");
        echo $main;
    }
}

$tp = new siteTemplate();
```

A function from my registration class:

```
public function get_username($uid) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE uid = $uid");
    $user_data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    echo $user_data['username'];
}
```

I can echo out data from my registration class in index.php

```
echo $user->get_username($uid);
```

BUT I can't do the same thing within my template files. What adjustments do I need to make to make this work together. Live example: http://www.aarongoff.com/i
Username: test
Password: test

If you look I'm echoing out "Logged in as: test"
But when I try to call for that variable within my template file it just displays "Logged in as:"

(I know there are SQL vulnerabilities, I'm just testing to get my classes to work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The true answer to this is that PHP *IS* a template! Use pure PHP code as your templates. Then you don't have to keep reimplementing every one of PHP's features in your ad hock template class.

This is called the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect and you should avoid it. Just use PHP directly, it's what it was made for.

What you should do is be disciplined about naming the PHP files, and separating concepts logically. But don't try to reimplement PHP in PHP.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is separate my PHP from my HTML so I can redesign easier. Is this not a common practice anymore?

Comment: Oh, it's certainly common practice (assuming you meant separate the HTML and the business logic, because separating PHP and HTML doesn't make sense.). Except you do it by separating the files, not the languages. Write your templates, and be strict about what goes in them vs the business logic files. But write them in PHP, and use them with `include()`.

Comment: Right now I have:

/includes/functions.php: Contains classes, no HTML whatsoever.

Comment: /templates/main.html: Contains HTML & vars <title>$siteName</title>

Comment: /index.php: includes functions.php and calls for main.html to create the front and back-end.

Comment: So basically I separate my logic from HTML, so everything is clean and when I want to do a template change, the variables can be easily moved around.

Comment: Change main.html to main.php, and do `<title><?=$siteName?></title>` and you are good to go. You can maintain your goal of just HTML and variables in templates with no problem. The only change is you write your templates in PHP.

Comment: That doesn't seem to make a difference because my PHP template class reads "$siteName" as a variable within the .html file. I'm wondering if I should dump the .phps?

Comment: Your class reads `$siteName` as a variable, but not `$user->get_username($uid)`. PHP reads both. I don't know what .phps is in your app since this is the first you mention it.

Comment: So how can I modify my class to read $user->get_username($uid) or other functions?

Comment: You'll need to string extract the function, then `eval()` it. It's not a good idea to do this, but it will work (although it may be pretty slow). You can probably also reimplement the PHP parser and use `call_user_func()` (or similar). I can't imagine that you would actually do this, but you asked so I will answer.

Comment: Change your extension to `$this->getTemplate("main.php")`